# How to add an image from the controller - Beginner

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I need to replace the image from the controller. How can i do this ?

CONTROLLER:

```
onNewsItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {



            var form = Ext.create("MyApp.view.mYV",{
                title:record.data.Gender,
                record:record
            });
// I NEED TO REPLACE THE DEFAULT.JPG IMAGE WITH SOME OTHER IMAGE. HOW CAN I ACCESS THE IMAGE VIEW FROM THE CONTROLLER ?
// MY WORKING

 var imageView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myvID > #myimage')[0];
    imageView.setValue(record.data.imageurl);

            this.getMainView().push(form);

    },
```

VIEW:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.mYV', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myv',

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        id: 'myvID',
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                height: 201,
                id: 'myimage',
                src: 'http://www.mysite/default.jpg'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

NOTE: UPDATE

I have a Navigation view, and from that navigation view i am navigating to the `mYV` view, and where i need to access the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have id for image.. what else you need

```
Ext.getCmp('myimage').setSrc(record.data.imageurl)
```

But that is not good practice and you can do the same in many ways

I encourage you to take look at [The dangers of Ext.getCmp() Screencast](http://vimeo.com/14816550)

**UPDATE**

**In View..**

remove id and give it itemID in image component

```
{
    xtype: 'image',
    height: 201,
    itemId: 'myimage',
    src: 'http://www.mysite/default.jpg'
 }
```

**In controller**

```
  var form = Ext.create("MyApp.view.mYV",{
     title:record.data.Gender,
     record:record
 });

 form.getComponent('myimage').setSrc(record.data.imageurl);
```

Comment: put this 'console.log(Ext.getCmp('myimage'))', check browser console and tell me what you got

Comment: Yup, that works. Can you please tell me the difference between ID and ITEMID.

Comment: id is available any where in project and itemId is available only within it's parent.. i always encourage you to make use of itemId and avoid using id.. for more take a at look this [secha forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?181881-itemId-vs-id) and [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Img-cfg-itemId)

Comment: if you avoid id.. you will avoid 'Ext.getCmp()' automatically and use itemId with 'parent.getComponent()' to get component